# Best way to write into the process.stdin in node.js and parse the line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, process

I'm proggraming in the MEAN stack , so I have my app.js and I want to build a process which will take commands from the shell its running on (process.stdin)
Currently I have tried :

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('What do you think of Node.js? ', (answer) => {
  // TODO: Log the answer in a database
  console.log(`Thank you for your valuable feedback: ${answer}`);

  rl.close();
});
```

but it writes my input twice and exit after 1 line . 
I need a readline function that will loop and take infinite commands from me . 
 
How can I get it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It exits because of:

```
rl.close();
```

If you want to read line by line interactively using readline:

```
rl.on('line', (line) => {
  // use line here
});
```

Another way that may be convenient for less interactive workflows but still works for interactive:

```
const filt = require('filt');
filt((line) => {
  // use line here
});
```

The second example uses the [`filt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/filt) module (disclaimer: I'm the author of that module).